# How to most generically iterate a sequence of items with a given type?

Tags: rust

The code below best describes the issue.

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

fn iterate<I: IntoIterator<Item=String>>(v: I) {
}

// iterate(&["foo".to_string()])
// error: type mismatch resolving `<&[collections::string::String; 1] as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == collections::string::String`:
// expected &-ptr,
// found struct `collections::string::String` [E0271]

// iterate(["foo".to_string()].iter())
// type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, collections::string::String> as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == collections::string::String`:
// expected &-ptr,
// found struct `collections::string::String` [E0271]

// This works !
iterate(vec!["foo".to_string()])
```

**How can I iterate anything (with a given item type) generically?**

#### Additional Notes

The intention is to allow users of such a function to pass in anything that can be iterated, or converted into an iterator.

Also I have the feeling that the actual issue is not really described in the compiler error - as the type it sees seems to be different from what it shows.

I am using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19) (built 2015-02-19)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at what the types are for your first case:

```
for i in &["foo".to_string()] {
    let () = i;
    // expected `&collections::string::String`,
    // found `()`
}
```

That is, the type of your iteration variable is `&String`, **not** on `String`, as your function wants. The same thing happens for your second case. The third case works:

```
for i in vec!["foo".to_string()] {
    let () = i;
    // expected `collections::string::String`,
    // found `()`
}
```

We can look at the implementation for `IntoIter` for [arrays](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.11.0/src/libcore/array.rs#L150-L158) and for [all 3 forms of Vec](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.10.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1330-L1388). Note that the implementation for `Vec<T>` *consumes* the vector, whereas the one for `&Vec<T>` must return an iterator over references to the elements.

You can't consume an array, so that iterator must always return references.

Here's an example that uses the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait that should do what you want:

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

fn iterate<I, S>(v: I)
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=S>,
          S: AsRef<str>
{}

fn main() {
    iterate(&["foo"]);
    iterate(&["foo".to_string()]);
    iterate(["foo".to_string()].iter());
    iterate(vec!["foo".to_string()]);
    iterate(&vec!["foo".to_string()]);
}
```

This says that we expect any concrete type that implements the trait `Iterator`. That iterator must yield a type that implements the trait `AsRef<str>`, allowing us to pass in {arrays,vectors,slices} of {`String`,`&str`}.

Comment: Why do the items differ ? Shouldn't iterators work similar for types which are the same semantically ? After all, a vec! is a bunch of strings on the heap, whereas an array allocates space for them on the stack. Why would iteration be different ?

Comment: Also, is there a way that allows me to most generically iterate anything that looks like a string ? Maybe 'String' should be 'T' with the right traits.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now I get it ! I should be able to debug this myself, and I am grateful that you pointed this out, hopefully allowing me to answer such questions myself in the future. Rust, as any good thing, doesn't come easily.